# main.js not updating when using kubernetes to deploy changes to frontend in web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kubernetes, caching, dockerfile

I can't get the frontend javascript files to update in the browser. When i check inside the container the files do seem to be updated

I've got 2 dockerfiles one for frontend and one for backend. 1 cluster 2 pods.

I'm using this

```
docker build --no-cache -f Dockerfile.frontend --build-arg -t 1.4 .
docker tag 1.4 gcr.io/myproject/mvp-frontend:latest
docker push gcr.io/myproject/mvp-frontend:1.4
kubectl apply -f frontend-deployment.yaml
kubectl set image deployment/frontend-deployment frontend=gcr.io/unity-ai-gen/mvp-frontend:1.4  --record
kubectl rollout restart deployment frontend-deployment
```

and even

```
kubectl delete pod frontend-deployment
```

Comment: You mention a `1.4` tag a couple of places in this command.  Is this number different for every build?  Before the cluster was running `1.3`, now it has `1.4`?  Have you gone through routine steps like clearing your browser cache and checking the content with command-line tools like `curl`?